# How to add data in aChartEngine to X-Axis

Tags: java, sqlite, arraylist, android-sqlite, achartengine

I have managed to obtain the data from the SQLite database and plot the actual values for the cube line chart view. Since the values should be plotted against the date which is also stored in the database in the format (dd-mm-yyyy) and is expected to be plotted on the x, I have difficulties how to actually realize that. Current parts of my code like this:

hapinessdb.class (SQLite database and the code to search for the date entries)

```
    /**
 * Return the date as a string and place it to ArrayList 
 * of strings. 
 * @return
 */
public ArrayList<String> getDataForDate() {
    ArrayList<String> dateValues = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_DATE, KEY_TIME,KEY_HAPPY,
            KEY_NORMAL, KEY_SAD };
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null,
            null, null, null, null); //Read the data from columns with cursor
    String result = "";
    int iDate= c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DATE);
    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        result = c.getString(iDate);
        dateValues.add(result);
    }
    return dateValues;
}
```

chart.class (method to obtain the ArrayList of date strings from happinessDb.class)

```
ArrayList<String> dateList = new ArrayList<String>();

    private void dateDataFromDb() {
    happinessDb dateInfo = new happinessDb(this);
    try {
        dateInfo.open();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ArrayList<String> data = dateInfo.getDataForDate();
    dateInfo.close();
    dateList = data; // Adds the dates to the String arrayList
```

My question is aimed towards, how to break the ArrayList of Strings and use them as part of the X-Axis series together with the bellow addHappyData method which plots the Integer values from ArralyList of Integers.

```
   private void addHappyData() {
    Integer x = 0;
    for (Integer happy : happyList) {
        mCurrentSeries.add(x += 20, happy);
    }
}
```

Thank you for your time,review, possible review and answer on this post,

brg

Animus

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: In chart class I am trying to obtain date values to be used for X-axis. addHappyData method is used to add values to the Y-axis. For the X-axis I would need dates from dateDataFromDb however I can not figure out how to modify in aChartEngine X-axis marks.